# Why does Application.getContext() return null?

Tags: android, android-context, android-testing, robolectric

Hello I am implementing and SDK, and I need a context for some pieces of code, so, for get access to a context, I implemented this in a Application class:

```
public class SDKApp extends Application {

    private static SDKApp sdkContext;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return sdkContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sdkContext = this;

    }

}
```

For test this, I am using Robolectric, but the context is returning null value:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class CallTest {

    private Context context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;

    @Test
    public void emailAuthenticationSuccessfulTest() {
        if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("dev")) {

            Context context = SDKApp.getContext();

            assertNotNull(context);
        }
    }
}
```

some idea about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add you SDKApp Class into your manifest application tag like this

```
<application
        android:name="SDKApp" // your complete package path to your SDKApp
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `SDKApp` is registered in `AndroidManifest.xml` like

```
<application
    android:name="SDKApp"
```

Then you may call `SDKApp.getContext()` otherwise you all time get null value from `SDKApp.getContext()`

Thanks.